# LaTeX font used by the derived geometry and geometric representation theory community

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

What is the LaTeX font used by many people in the derived geometry and geometric Langlands community, e.g. the font used in [this book](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Egaitsgde/GL/Vol1.pdf) by D. Gaitsgory and N. Rozenblyum (I have also seen this font used by people like S. Raskin and R. Reich, etc.) ? It is very similar to the usual font, but many of the binary operations like `\times, \otimes, \oplus` as well as the symbol `\infty` (see the picture below). Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around in the source files as @Gaussler suggested, I've found that the two important packages are `foekfont` and `MnSymbol`. One thing to note is that in order to use these along with the standard AMS packages like `amsmath` or `amsfonts` (see @Ingmar's comment), XeLaTeX will be a more stable compiler than LaTeX or pdfLaTeX. I'm not sure why this is the case, though.

Comment: I very much doubt that this is compiled using XeLaTeX. Very few professional mathematicians use that engine when writing in English (especially not when using Computer Modern). For some advanced applications, some people might use LuaTeX, but in all other cases, people usually stick to pdfTeX. (And from my personal knowledge of Gaitsgory and Rozenblyum, I don’t think the features offered by XeTeX or LuaTeX are of any interest to them.)

Comment: @Gaussler I hear you, and I do think it is strange that I can only get the errors to stop showing up by using XeLaTeX, but since I'm not a LaTeX expert I have not been able to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Then you might ask that as a separate question. `;-)`

Answer (score 3):

That’s just Computer Modern, probably along with some extra packages that change the appearance of some symbols (I didn’t check which ones). All articles authored and coauthored by Gaitsgory have this same layout, so if you want to see how it’s made, you can download the source code of any of his articles on arXiv, such as [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.01906). The source is one single (huge) `.tex` file, so simply download it and add a `.tex` file extension, then you can read it.

Comment: He uses the following packages: 
`\usepackage{amsmath}`
`\usepackage{amsxtra}`
`\usepackage{amscd}`
`\usepackage{amsthm}`
`\usepackage{amsfonts}`
`\usepackage{amssymb}`
`\usepackage{eucal}`